# IOS - Why is the label not updating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uilabel

I have a View with one label that I'm trying to update with some text.   I'm sure the issue is something simple, but I can't seem to narrow it down.

I'm pulling some Parse data to populate the label, but the issue is not with the Parse data because even if I just attempt to assign some static text the label is not working.  I'm guessing there's something that I'm overlooking when the connections.  I have the label connected to the header file with via IBOutlet.  I have the view in the storyboard's class set to the proper file.

Here's some screenshots of my configuration.  If you see my error please let me know! :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And you are calling the update code from the main (UI) thread?

Comment: In which method are you try to set the `self.performerLabelTest.text` ? It sound like you are calling the outlet before the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: At the moment everything is happening on the main thread.  I have the exact same code on another view that works.  There's not much happening so I don't think I'm tying up the thread causing the view not to update.  The UI is fully responsive at all times.

Comment: at which point are you trying to access the label?

Comment: You got two good suggestions already. Just one more thing to look at - less likely but possible: Check whether you really assigned the correct view controller class in IB to this view. Especially as you are having "exactly the same code on antoher view controller". You may have mixed them up while copying or so.

Comment: @rckoenes Within the NRMPerformerViewController.m file within a ConfigureView method created.  The method is being created without a problem and the data is populated to that method as you can see from the NSLog entry in one of the screenshots.

Comment: Since the detailItem seems to exist. Just to be sure you are updating the label on the main thread try this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.performerLabelText.text = ...
});

Comment: What happens if you try to set the text of the label in the viewDidLoad method with some random data?

Comment: @rckoenes I figured it out!!!  Although the code was being called within the method I had forgotten to call the method under the viewDidLoad!  haha.  I just doublechecked the and noticed the missing code.  Thanks a lot!  I knew it had to be something simple but it's 6am here my Brain is a little overtired. :-) Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are calling to the `self.performerLabelTest.text` before the view is loaded.

Call the `self.performerLabelTest.text` after or in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten to call the method from within the viewDidLoad.  Thanks again for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your label is connected to the Performer view(not to the UILabel) in connection panel. Just change that in connection panel.

Comment: It's working now.  I had forgotten to call the method in the viewDidLoad. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the attribute as "STRONG" instead of weak .

> ```
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *performerLabelList;
> ```

Comment: Not needed since the superview will retain the label.